# Get a value from table 'eav/config' by client id

Tags: magento-1.9, php, eav, eav-attributes

**Code**

```
$users = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection();

$i = 1;
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
$id = $user->getId();

$customerObj  = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($id);
print_r($customerObj);
}
```

**Return**

```
[entity_id] => 91
[entity_type_id] => 2
[attribute_set_id] => 0
[increment_id] => 
[parent_id] => 95
[created_at] => 2016-04-29T01:09:49-03:00
[updated_at] => 2016-08-26 19:31:42
[is_active] => 1
[prefix] => 
[firstname] => Luis Gustavo 
[middlename] => 
[lastname] => Carvalho
[suffix] => 
[company] => 
[city] => São Paulo
[country_id] => BR
[region] => São Paulo
[postcode] => 08042-110
[telephone] => (11) 27385-808
[fax] => 11-948563521
[vat_id] => 
[mobile] => (11) 94856-3521
[esmart_reference] => 
[esmart_sms_message] => 
[esmart_signature_handwriting] => 
[esmart_sms_confirmation_mobile] => 
[region_id] => 508
[esmart_address_type] => 0
[esmart_relationship] => 0
[esmart_occasion] => 0
[esmart_fl_sms_message] => 0
[esmart_fl_sms_confirmation] => 0
[street] => Rua Parmênides
            309
            a
            Cidade Nova São Miguel
```

These fields bring me 0 because they are custom attributes and when they have they have placed a value text, how do I get the numerical value of these fields?

`[esmart_address_type] => 0`
`[esmart_relationship] => 0`
`[esmart_occasion] => 0`
`[esmart_fl_sms_message] => 0`
`[esmart_fl_sms_confirmation] => 0`

**What I need**

When collecting the data they bring me the value or label instead of 0
.
As in the code below, how can I do this?

**Code**

```
$config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');

$attribute = $config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'esmart_address_type');
$values    = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
print_r($values);
```

**Return**

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => 8993
        [label] => Residencial
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => 8994
        [label] => Comercial
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
echo $customerObj->getResource()
              ->getAttribute('esmart_address_type')
              ->getFrontend()
              ->getValue($customerObj);
```

Comment: It did not work, it keeps returning me 0

Comment: Are you sure for entity I'd 90 have contain that attribute value?

Comment: Return -> string(2) "No"

Comment: Yes, i have sure

Comment: Find attribute I'd from db and search into customer-address relevant table for that address id

Comment: The table that has this attribute is `eav_attribute_option_value` but I can not pull the data from this table through the client

Comment: The table contain option value.it should save value into customer_address_entity_text based on attribute type per address wise

Comment: I do not have the data there, it only has street addresses

Comment: The other attributes I have it usually pulls giving a getNameAttribute () the attributes that are dropdown and have the numeric values ​​value = "1" work. But the attributes that have value values ​​in text value = "yes" go wrong. This value "yes" is not saved anywhere

Comment: I don't think you know Magento stucture for Save data